# Node.js JSON.parse Unexpected token error

Tags: node.js

I have to import content for Json url in other site. (its almost more than 100K content)

here code i use (i am using requset for download josn file, and mongodb for saving data)

```
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
var content = JSON.parse(body);
    // ....
    }
})
```

Everything work well but after 50K content imoprted i got this error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at Object.parse (native)
    at Request._callback (/home/app/app.js:58:30)
    at Request.self.callback (/home/app/node_modules/request/request.js:360:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/app/node_modules/request/request.js:1202:14)
    at Request.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/app/node_modules/request/request.js:1150:12)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:944:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:448:13)
```

i will be appreciated if tell where i am wrong.

Comment: Just a wild guess, but maybe there's an unexpected token ">" in your JSON.

Comment: @torazaburo i found cause problem , in my source some page JSON is broken and have this error `Malformed JSON` , now i just need to know how i can prevent node from exiting my app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the source of the JSON file? Is it reliable? Review the JSON that is being parsed - "<" is very unusual for JSON, so it's probably not properly escaped.

I would also put a `try { } catch(e) { }` statement around your `JSON.parse(body)`;

Comment: here  is my source https://goo.gl/SJnTC0 Is it reliable? well its only option i have.

Comment: Hmm.. are you sure that's what you are pulling? It was `2.6kb` in size and when I ran `JSON.parse()` in my browser console, it parsed fine. You are saying what you are downloading is 100K. Is that 100Kb? Please clarifyi

Comment: i using request for downloading and using `JSON.parse()` method , i dont think be any different.

Comment: i found cause problem , in my source some page JSON is broken and have this error  `Malformed JSON` , now i just need to know how i can prevent node from exiting my app.

Comment: Aha - I was right! try catch shouldn't end process btw - did you use it right?

Comment: Anyway, google `process.on('uncaughtexception')`. It's bad practice, but will prevent node from crashing. You should actually handle the malformed JSON instead.

Comment: On second though, show me your try catch code. It should totally stop it from crashing.

Comment: here is code i used `try {
    var content = JSON.parse(body);
}
catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
}`

Comment: That's odd. Do the process.on('uncaughtexception') function and log the result.

Comment: after a review my code and some changes its working , thanks for helping.